# How to combine two api in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have two API - getAllTeamMemberData & getAllTeamData. Both the API are same, return same list of employee but the difference is in its requestBody type. getAllTeamMemberData needs empid which is provided by user and the other API getAllTeamData need managerId. Is there any possibility to combine this two API into one API (for eg - getAllTeam ) and return a list of employee according to the body (i.e empid & managerId) they receive?

Service class of API 1 -

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository repo;

Public ServiceResponse (EmployeeDTO employeeDto){
List = repo.getEmpId
.
.

}
```

Service class of API 2 -

```
Public ServiceResponse (EmployeeDTO employeeDto){
List = repo.getManagerId
.
.

}
```

After this all code is exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

you can put **managerId** and **empId** both in request body.

Based on the condition if you send managerId then it will fetch data of managers otherwise employees.